# In GWT, rootpanel.get() doesn't find the html id tag?

Tags: gwt

`RootPanel.get("stockList").add(mainPanel)`
And in my html file

```html
<body>
   <h1>StockWatcher</h1>
   <div id="stockList"></div>
  </body>
```

Why can it not find the id?  When I run the program it says "html tag with id "stockList" not found."

Here is the complete code. and project structure
package com.mySampleApplication.client;

```
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Document;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.*;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

public class MySampleApplication implements EntryPoint {

    private VerticalPanel mainPanel = new VerticalPanel();
    private FlexTable stocksFlexTable = new FlexTable();
    private HorizontalPanel addPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
    private TextBox newSymbolTextBox = new TextBox();
    private Button addStockButton = new Button("Add");
    private Label lastUpdatedLabel = new Label();

    /**
     * Entry point method.
     */
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        // Create table for stock data.
        stocksFlexTable.setText(0, 0, "Symbol");
        stocksFlexTable.setText(0, 1, "Price");
        stocksFlexTable.setText(0, 2, "Change");
        stocksFlexTable.setText(0, 3, "Remove");

        // Assemble Add Stock panel.
        addPanel.add(newSymbolTextBox);
        addPanel.add(addStockButton);

        // Assemble Main panel.
        mainPanel.add(stocksFlexTable);
        mainPanel.add(addPanel);
        mainPanel.add(lastUpdatedLabel);


        // Associate the Main panel with the HTML host page.
       RootPanel.get("stockList").add(mainPanel);




        // Move cursor focus to the input box.
        newSymbolTextBox.setFocus(true);

    }

}
```

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ow7zg.png)

Comment: What linker are you using? Are you sure that gwt itself is bootstraped? Why you don't try to debug using superdevmode?

Comment: Can you post the error message?